# Freeze a cell in Colab Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

The answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48146188/how-to-freeze-a-cell-alone-with-its-outputs-on-a-jupyter-notebook) question indicate different ways to freeze a cell in a Juypter notebook. How can I get the same functionality in a Colaboratory notebook?

The linked thread mentions the [freeze](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/freeze/readme.html) extension that can be used with jupyter notebooks, but I am unable to figure out as to how I can use the same in a Colaboratory notebook.