# Jupyter notebook - option to prevent re-execution of a cell?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I want to know if there is an option in the Notebook UI or some magic command (for a cell) that prevents its re-execution.
For e.g., if I execute a few cells in sequence, and wanted to go back to re-run the first cell, then I should be prevented from doing that.

Answer (score 1):

For the old Jupyter notebook see: [How to freeze a cell alone with its outputs on a jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48146188/how-to-freeze-a-cell-alone-with-its-outputs-on-a-jupyter-notebook).

For JupyterLab there is [no extension yet](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/4213) but there is an agreement that this is a good idea. Everyone can become an extension author and contribute it. A good starting point is the [Extension Developer guide](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extension/extension_dev.html).

If the cell has no output that you care about you can use a handy trick of temporarily switching its type to "raw" (as raw cells don't get executed). It can be done with a keyboard sequence of <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd>; then to restore its type to "code" cell you can use <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>y</kbd>.